# finding the limit of = $\ln(\frac{2x}{\pi})\cdot e^{\frac{1}{\cos x}}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I need to find the following limit :

$$ \lim_{x \to \pi/2^-} \ln\left(\frac{2x}{\pi}\right)\cdot e^{\frac{1}{\cos x}}$$

The limit is definitely $-\infty$, yet I don't understand why what I've done is wrong.

$$\cos \left(\frac{\pi}{2} + x \right) =_0 1-\frac{(\pi+2x)^2}{4} +o(x^2)$$
So :
$$ \frac{1}{\cos \left(\frac{\pi}{2} + x\right)}
 =_0 1-\left(1+\frac{(\pi+2x)^2}{4} +o\left(x^2\right)\right)+o(x) = -\frac{(\pi+2x)^2}{4}+o(x)$$ 
Hence :
$$ e^{\frac{1}{\cos (\frac{\pi}{2} + x)}} =_0 1-\frac{(\pi+2x)^2}{4}+o(x)$$

An here what I've obtained is already false because :

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}  1+\frac{(\pi+2x)^2}{4}+o(x) \ne -\infty$$

Comment: Why do you consider $\cos \left(\frac{\pi}{2} + x \right)$?

Comment: The best way to avoid error is to change variable $x=\frac{\pi}2-y$ in order to deal with a limit to $0^+$.

Comment: Yes I think I messed up, I was wondering if it was possible to find the answer using Taylor expansion ?

Comment: Yes it is possible of course, even if not necessary, we can use also Taylor. In any case is better make a change of variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x=\frac{\pi}2-y$ with $y\to 0^+$ then

$$\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}^-} \ln\left(\frac{2x}{\pi}\right)\cdot e^{\frac{1}{\cos x}}=\lim_{y \rightarrow 0^+} \ln\left(1-\frac{\pi y}{2}\right)\cdot e^{\frac{1}{\sin y}}=-\infty$$

indeed

$$\ln\left(1-\frac{\pi y}{2}\right)\cdot e^{\frac{1}{\sin y}}=\frac{\ln\left(1- \frac{\pi y}{2} \right)}{\frac{\pi y}{2}}\cdot \frac{\pi y}{2}e^{\frac{1}{\sin y}}$$

and

$$\frac{\ln\left(1- \frac{\pi y}{2} \right)}{\frac{\pi y}{2}}\to -1$$

$$\frac{\pi y}{2} e^{\frac{1}{\sin y}}=\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{e^{\frac{1}{\sin y}}}{\frac{1}{\sin y}}\frac{y}{\sin y}\to +\infty$$

Comment: Do you think it's possible to find the answer using taylor expansion ?

Comment: @auhasard Yes of course itis possible for the log term, but it is simpler by the change of variable. Otherwise we need to expand  around $x=\pi/2$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! Yet the problem is that when I expand : $\cos x$ at $x \pi/2$ then I am getting trouble expanding : $1/ \cos x$ at $x = \pi/2$...

Comment: Because is it possible to expand $1/(1-x)$ at $x =1$ ?

Comment: @auhasard we can't expand the $e^{\frac 1 {\cos x}}$ term but only the log term.

Comment: Ok so in this case using the Taylor expansion doesn't help right ? I mean the only solution to this limit is yours ?

Comment: @auhasard Maybe some other different way is possible but not directly by Taylor. In my opinion when possible the resolution by standard limits is always the best and more instructive way.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time for helping me. I think, that I should directly spot that : $e^{1/ \cos x}$ can't be expand, and that : $P(x)e^{1 / \cos x}$ is not a form that is going to help. So, all of this are saying that using Taylor expansion can't work

Answer (score 1):

If you want the solution using Taylor series and equivalents, let, as gimusi did, $x=\frac{\pi}2-y$ with $y\to 0^+$
$$\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}^-} \ln\left(\frac{2x}{\pi}\right)\, e^{\frac{1}{\cos (x)}}=\lim_{y \rightarrow 0^+} \ln\left(1-\frac{\pi }{2}y\right)\, e^{{\csc (y)}}$$

Now, using Taylor series built at $y=0$
$$\csc(y)=\frac{1}{y}+\frac{y}{6}+O\left(y^3\right)\implies  e^{{\csc (y)}}\sim e^{\frac{1}{y}}$$
$$\ln\left(1-\frac{\pi }{2}y\right)=-\frac{2 y}{\pi }-\frac{2 y^2}{\pi ^2}+O\left(y^3\right)$$
$$\lim_{y \rightarrow 0^+} \ln\left(1-\frac{\pi }{2}y\right)\, e^{{\csc (y)}}\sim -\frac{2}{\pi }\lim_{y \rightarrow 0^+}\left(y\,e^{\frac{1}{y}}\right)=-\infty$$